# How to apply json_normalize on entire pandas column

Tags: python, json

I have a dataframe with LISTS(with dicts) as column values . My intention is to normalize entire column(all rows). I found way to normalize a single row . However, I'm unable to apply the same function for the entire dataframe or column.

```
data = {'COLUMN': [ [{'name': 'WAG 01', 'id': '105F', 'state': 'available', 'nodes': 3,'volumes': [{'state': 'available', 'id': '330172', 'name': 'q_-4144d4e'}, {'state': 'available', 'id': '275192', 'name': 'p_3089d821ae', }]}], [{'name': 'FEC 01', 'id': '382E', 'state': 'available', 'nodes': 4,'volumes': [{'state': 'unavailable', 'id': '830172', 'name': 'w_-4144d4e'}, {'state': 'unavailable', 'id': '223192', 'name': 'g_3089d821ae', }]}], [{'name': 'ASD 01', 'id': '303F', 'state': 'available', 'nodes': 6,'volumes': [{'state': 'unavailable', 'id': '930172', 'name': 'e_-4144d4e'}, {'state': 'unavailable', 'id': '245192', 'name': 'h_3089d821ae', }]}] ] }

source_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

> source_df looks like below :

[image]

As per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html I managed to get output for one row.

> Code to apply for one row:

```
Target_df = json_normalize(source_df['COLUMN'][0], 'volumes', ['name','id','state','nodes'], record_prefix='volume_')
```

> Output for above code :

[image]

I would like to know how we can achieve desired output for the entire column

> Expected output:

[image]

EDIT:
@lostCode , below is the input with nan and empty list

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
Target_df=pd.concat([json_normalize(source_df['COLUMN'][key], 'volumes', ['name','id','state','nodes'], record_prefix='volume_') for key in source_df.index]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    volume_state    volume_id   volume_name  name   id     state     nodes
0   available       330172      q_-4144d4e   WAG 01 105F    available   3
1   available       275192      p_3089d821ae WAG 01 105F    available   3
2   unavailable     830172      w_-4144d4e   FEC 01 382E    available   4
3   unavailable     223192      g_3089d821ae FEC 01 382E    available   4
4   unavailable     930172      e_-4144d4e   ASD 01 303F    available   6
5   unavailable     245192      h_3089d821ae ASD 01 303F    available   6
```

`concat`, is used to concatenate a dataframe list, in this case the list that is generated using json_normalize is concatenated on all rows of source_df

**You can use to check type of source_df:**

```
Target_df=pd.concat([json_normalize(source_df['COLUMN'][key], 'volumes', ['name','id','state','nodes'], record_prefix='volume_') for key in source_df.index if isinstance(source_df['COLUMN'][key],list)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked for this input.For input with 'nan' values I'm getting the below error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: edited my question with new input..thanks for the reply!!

Comment: The error is generated when it is not a `list`, that is, with np.nan, so a condition is added to check if it is a list. If it is not, do not try to perform `json_normalize`, avoiding the error. I have uploaded this code at the end of my answer. Tell me if you can accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

Target_df=source_df.apply(json_normalize)

Comment: recommend: `target_df = source_df.apply(pd.json_normalize)`